# How to get client Id through nginx

Tags: spring-boot, nginx, nginx-config, clientid

I am working on a project to manage the logs from clients, I am using nginx to redirect links in my projects. This my config file (I run nginx with docker):

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    

    client_body_timeout  128;
    client_header_timeout 128;
    keepalive_timeout 128;

    proxy_read_timeout 600;
    proxy_connect_timeout 600;
    proxy_send_timeout 600;
    

    #include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    client_max_body_size 100M;


    server {
        listen       80;
    server_name sale.ala.vn;
    rewrite ^.*$ https://$host$request_uri break;
    }

    server {
        listen       443 ssl;
        ssl_certificate     /etc/nginx/ssl.crt/cert.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl.key/private.key;
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        server_name sale.ala.vn;

        location / {
        rewrite ^/$ $scheme://$host/msale/ break;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarder-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header   Host      $http_host;
            proxy_pass   http://10.10.34.162;
        }

    }
}
```

I want to get the real client IP using spring boot, but the result that I got is always the IP of nginx. How can I fix this? Thank you so much.